# Creating a column in metabase query tool depending on if another column contains unique value

Tags: sql, case, metabase

I am trying to use the matabase query tool to create a new column of 1s and 0s.

example data

```
id    value
1     10
2     0
2     15
2     10
```

I want to create a new column that contains a 1 if the id is unique and `value > 0` and 0 otherwise. Using the query tool in Metabase I can create a new column that is 1 or 0 depending on if `value > 0` using

```
case([value] > 0, 1, 0)
```

But this gives,

```
id    value    new_col
1     10       1
2     0        0
2     15       1
2     10       1
```

As I want to calculate `sum([new_col])` later in the query this gives the wrong answer as I would get 3 instead of 2 (as only 2 unique id's have `value > 0`)

How can my case statement also check if the id is unique?

Answer (score 0):

for INT you need to use "If" not "Case"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).